# Upload in Dailymotion using Google Drive or via email

Tags: google-drive-api, dailymotion-api

I have some video in google drive. Can I upload them directly from Google Drive to dailymotion ? or can I upload file via email as attachment ?

Answer (score 0):

Upload via email is not a possible option, but if your videos have a public url, you can upload them to dailymotion directly using the api.

See the documentation at https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#upload-publish-video. Skip steps 2 and 3, and directly post the video using the url field (set to your video source url). basically, you have to make a POST request to `https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos` with the required parameters, among which `url=<YOUR_VIDEO_URL>`